# Checking for data uniqueness in AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularjs-controller, angularfire

Using AngularFire, I want to add an object to my angularFireCollection ONLY if the "name" is unique.  My data is structured like so:

```
- ClientList
    - dsk32923k   <-Random unique ID created by AngularFire
        - name : Brian
        - birthday : 3/9/82
          ...
    - skjdsjkl3  
        - name : John
        - birthday : 6/3/90
          ...
```

For example, I wish to verify that "Brian" is a unique name before adding the data object to the ClientList.  I want this to be accomplished inside an Angular controller.  What is the "Angular way" of making that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit hard to do this with `angularFireCollection` without iterating over all the entries to check for duplicates. It might be easier to use `angularFire` and use the name as the unique key:

```js
function MyController($scope, angularFire) {
  var url = "https://<my-firebase>.firebaseio.com/ClientList";
  var promise = angularFire(url, $scope, "users", {});
  promise.then(function() {
    $scope.addUser = function(user) {
      if ($scope.users[user.name]) {
        throw new Error("User already exists!");
      } else {
        $scope.users[name] = user;
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Hope this helps!